# php remembering a session

Tags: php, session, variables, superglobals

Im trying to stop users of my spacebook page from navigating to other pages without having logged in first. I understand I am supposed to use session variables. I know I have the user remembered on a specific session by entering `session_start()`; at the top of the page. Would a new class file be necessary have the browser remember the client is logged in or not? Would  the session need to be stored stored in the class object? If a user navigated to a page where access was authorised before they could get there where would I store the if/else statement needed in a seperate php file?

If a new class was necessary Im thinking it would look something like this:

```
class Loggedin {
    private $isLoggedIn;

    public function Loggedin($username) {
        if (array_key_exists($username, $this->isLoggedIn) && ($this->isLoggedIn[$username] == $password))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After the User has been logged in you can simply store the User ID in the $_SESSION variable like this:

login.php:

```
if (login_correct($userid, $password)) { 
   // Login successful
   $_SESSION['user_id'] = $userid; 
}
```

An other PHP-file could look like this:

```
if (null !== $_SESSION['user_id']) { 
    // User ist logged in... 
} else { 
    // User is not logged in! 
}
```

Your logout.php can look like this:

```
$_SESSION['user_id] = null;
```

Comment: ok thanks Markus, do you not think a session destroy would be neccessary for logging out? Also the first if statement you had there, could that go after the session_start(); at the top of the page?

Comment: After using session_destroy() your $_SESSION variable will be empty. You can use this for logout if you want to remove all data from $_SESSION. But $_SESSION['user_id'] will work as well.

$_SESSION should be used after session was started by session_start().

Comment: ok - could you put the session[user_id] within a hyperlink so it would clear the session once this was clicked?

Comment: The $_SESSION variable will be available for all requests of a user. So your logout.php must only contain `session_destroy()` or `$_SESSION['user_id']` and can be called without any parameters. E.g. your logout-hyperlink can look like this: `<a href="logout.php">logout</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are *way* over-thinking this.

- Passwords never get stored for longer than they are needed (i.e. the initial authorization request, so your `$password` is not necessary, not that it's defined anyway).
- You have access to `$_SESSION` everywhere.  It's up to you if you want to wrap it in a class.
- The authentication check is as simple as `isset($_SESSION['username'])` (assuming you set that session value on login.

Comment: do u think a loggedin class is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

The `$_SESSION` variable in PHP is something they called a [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php). This means that this variable is accessible from any scope throughout your application. Simply use `$_SESSION`.

Same goes with `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST`, `$_SERVER` and `$_ENV`. I'm sure I'm missing one somewhere :D

Answer (score 0):

Remembering a user can be as simple as (after login success):

```
$_SESSION['userid'] = 1234;
```

Another page would query it like so:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
    // user is logged in
}
```

There's no need to store an object in the session to accomplish this.

Comment: ok thanks Jack so once Ive logged in I would use the if statement in every page?

Comment: What about generating an error message by adding an else statement ehrn tryin to accessing a page they should not be?

Comment: @JamesByrne sure, go for it :)